# Hibernate Operation is not working

Tags: hibernate

This code is not working properly in the following section. How can I resolve the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property> 
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.241.47.160:1521:orcl</property> 
                    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">training</property> <property 
                    name="hibernate.connection.password">training</property> <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">150</property> 
                    <property name="show_sql">true</property> <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property> 
                    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->

                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzadelivery</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
                <!-- Mapping files -->
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.Customer" />
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.MemberShipCard" />
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.Pizza" />
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.PizzaOrder" />
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.PizzaOrderDetail" />
                <mapping class="com.cts.pizza.pojo.SalesBoy" />
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>




        @Entity
        @Table(name="SALESBOYS")
        public class SalesBoy {

            private Integer salesBoyId;
            private String salesBoyName;
            private String address;
            private String contactNo;
            private String emailId;
            private Set<PizzaOrder> pizzaOrders;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            public Integer getSalesBoyId() {
                return salesBoyId;
            }
            public void setSalesBoyId(Integer salesBoyId) {
                this.salesBoyId = salesBoyId;
            }

            @Column(name="SALESBOYNAME")
            public String getSalesBoyName() {
                return salesBoyName;
            }
            public void setSalesBoyName(String salesBoyName) {
                this.salesBoyName = salesBoyName;
            }

            @Column(name="ADDRESS")
            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }
            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            @Column(name="CONTACTNO")
            public String getContactNo() {
                return contactNo;
            }
            public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
                this.contactNo = contactNo;
            }

            @Column(name="EMAILID")
            public String getEmailId() {
                return emailId;
            }
            public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
                this.emailId = emailId;
            }

            @OneToMany
            @JoinColumn(name = "SALESBOY_ID")
            public Set<PizzaOrder> getPizzaOrders() {
                return pizzaOrders;
            }
            public void setPizzaOrders(Set<PizzaOrder> pizzaOrders) {
                this.pizzaOrders = pizzaOrders;
            }

        }


    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

    @Embeddable
    public class PizzaOrderDetailId implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int orderId;
        private int pizzaId;
        public int getOrderId() {
            return orderId;
        }
        public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }
        public int getPizzaId() {
            return pizzaId;
        }
        public void setPizzaId(int pizzaId) {
            this.pizzaId = pizzaId;
        }

    }
    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PIZZAORDERDETAIL")
    public class PizzaOrderDetail {

        @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="orderId",column=@Column(name="ORDER_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="pizzaId",column=@Column(name="PIZZA_ID"))
        })
        @EmbeddedId
        private PizzaOrderDetailId pizzaOrderDetailId;

        private int quantity;

        private double price;



        public PizzaOrderDetailId getPizzaOrderDetailId() {
            return pizzaOrderDetailId;
        }

        public void setPizzaOrderDetailId(PizzaOrderDetailId pizzaOrderDetailId) {
            this.pizzaOrderDetailId = pizzaOrderDetailId;
        }

        @Column(name="QUANTITY")
        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        @Column(name="PRICE")
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

    }




    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PIZZAORDER")
    public class PizzaOrder {

        private int orderId;
        private Date orderDate;
        private double totalAmount;
        private int customerNo;
        private Integer salesBoyId;

        private Set<PizzaOrderDetail> pizzaOrderDetail;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="ORDERID")
        public int getOrderId() {
            return orderId;
        }
        public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }

        @Column(name="ORDERDATE")
        public Date getOrderDate() {
            return orderDate;
        }
        public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
            this.orderDate = orderDate;
        }

        @Column(name="TOTALAMOUNT")
        public double getTotalAmount() {
            return totalAmount;
        }
        public void setTotalAmount(double totalAmount) {
            this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        }

        @Column(name="CUSTOMER_NO")
        public int getCustomerNo() {
            return customerNo;
        }
        public void setCustomerNo(int customerNo) {
            this.customerNo = customerNo;
        }

        @Column(name="SALESBOY_ID")
        public Integer getSalesBoyId() {
            return salesBoyId;
        }
        public void setSalesBoyId(Integer salesBoyId) {
            this.salesBoyId = salesBoyId;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
        public Set<PizzaOrderDetail> getPizzaOrderDetail() {
            return pizzaOrderDetail;
        }

        public void setPizzaOrderDetail(Set<PizzaOrderDetail> pizzaOrderDetail) {
            this.pizzaOrderDetail = pizzaOrderDetail;
        }
    }


    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PIZZA")
    public class Pizza {

        private int pizzaId;

        private String pizzaName;

        private Set<PizzaOrderDetail> pizzaOrderDetail;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="PIZZAID")
        public int getPizzaId() {
            return pizzaId;
        }

        public void setPizzaId(int pizzaId) {
            this.pizzaId = pizzaId;
        }

        @Column(name="PIZZANAME")
        public String getPizzaName() {
            return pizzaName;
        }

        public void setPizzaName(String pizzaName) {
            this.pizzaName = pizzaName;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="PIZZA_ID")
        public Set<PizzaOrderDetail> getPizzaOrderDetail() {
            return pizzaOrderDetail;
        }

        public void setPizzaOrderDetail(Set<PizzaOrderDetail> pizzaOrderDetail) {
            this.pizzaOrderDetail = pizzaOrderDetail;
        }

    }


    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MEMBERSHIPCARD")
    public class MemberShipCard {

        private int cardNo;

        private int pointsEarned;

        private int customerNo;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="CARDNO")
        public int getCardNo() {
            return cardNo;
        }

        public void setCardNo(int cardNo) {
            this.cardNo = cardNo;
        }


        @Column(name="POINTSEARNED")
        public int getPointsEarned() {
            return pointsEarned;
        }

        public void setPointsEarned(int pointsEarned) {
            this.pointsEarned = pointsEarned;
        }

        @Column(name="CUSTOMER_NO")
        public int getCustomerNo() {
            return customerNo;
        }

        public void setCustomerNo(int customerNo) {
            this.customerNo = customerNo;
        }

    }


    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="CUSTOMER")
    public class Customer {

        private int customerNo;

        private String custName;

        private String contactNo;

        private String emailId;

        private Address address;

        private Set<PizzaOrder> pizzaOrders;

        private MemberShipCard memberShipCard;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="CUSTOMERNO")
        public int getCustomerNo() {
            return customerNo;
        }

        public void setcustomerNo(int customerNo) {
            this.customerNo = customerNo;
        }

        @Column(name="CUSTOMERNAME")
        public String getCustName() {
            return custName;
        }

        public void setCustName(String custName) {
            this.custName = custName;
        }


        @Column(name="CONTACTNO")
        public String getContactNo() {
            return contactNo;
        }

        public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
            this.contactNo = contactNo;
        }


        @Column(name="EMAILID")
        public String getEmailId() {
            return emailId;
        }

        public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
            this.emailId = emailId;
        }


        @Embedded
        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(Address address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_NO")
        public Set<PizzaOrder> getPizzaOrders() {
            return pizzaOrders;
        }

        public void setPizzaOrders(Set<PizzaOrder> pizzaOrders) {
            this.pizzaOrders = pizzaOrders;
        }

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_NO")
        public MemberShipCard getMemberShipCard() {
            return memberShipCard;
        }

        public void setMemberShipCard(MemberShipCard memberShipCard) {
            this.memberShipCard = memberShipCard;
        }

    }


    package com.cts.pizza.pojo;

    import javax.persistence.Column;

    public class Address {

        private String doorNo;

        private String street;

        private String city;

        private String state;

        private int pinCode;


        @Column(name="DOORNO")
        public String getDoorNo() {
            return doorNo;
        }

        public void setDoorNo(String doorNo) {
            this.doorNo = doorNo;
        }


        @Column(name="STREET")
        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }


        @Column(name="CITY")
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        @Column(name="STATE")
        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Column(name="PINCODE")
        public int getPinCode() {
            return pinCode;
        }

        public void setPinCode(int pinCode) {
            this.pinCode = pinCode;
        }

    }


    package com.cts.pizza.main;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;


    public class HibernateUtil {
        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            try {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static void shutdown() {
            // Close caches and connection pools
            getSessionFactory().close();
        }
    }

    package com.cts.pizza.main;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import com.cts.pizza.dao.CustomerDAO;
    import com.cts.pizza.dao.OrderDAO;
    import com.cts.pizza.dao.PizzaDAO;
    import com.cts.pizza.dao.PizzaStoreDAO;
    import com.cts.pizza.dao.SalesBoyDAO;
    import com.cts.pizza.pojo.Address;
    import com.cts.pizza.pojo.Customer;
    import com.cts.pizza.pojo.MemberShipCard;
    import com.cts.pizza.pojo.Pizza;
    import com.cts.pizza.pojo.PizzaOrder;

    public class PizzaStoreController {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            CustomerDAO customer = new CustomerDAO();

            // Store Customer Detials starts here
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.setContactNo("9562055522");
            cust.setCustName("Mani");
            cust.setEmailId("mani@gmail.com");

            Address address = new Address();
            address.setCity("Kochi");
            address.setDoorNo("3g");
            address.setPinCode(682030);
            address.setState("Kerala");
            address.setStreet("edachira");
            customer.storeCustomerDetails(cust, address);
            // Store Customer Detials ends here     

            // Enroll for MemberShipCard starts here
            MemberShipCard card = new MemberShipCard();
            card.setPointsEarned(100);
            customer.enrollForMemberShipCard(cust.getCustomerNo(), card);
            // Enroll for MemberShipCard ends here

            // Create Pizzas starts here
            PizzaDAO pizza = new PizzaDAO();
            Set<Pizza> pizzas = new HashSet<Pizza>();
            Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza();
            pizza1.setPizzaName("Chicken pizza");
            pizzas.add(pizza1);
            Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza();
            pizza2.setPizzaName("Veg pizza");
            pizzas.add(pizza2);
            pizza.createPizzas(pizzas);
            // Create Pizzas ends here

            // CreateOrder starts here
            OrderDAO order = new OrderDAO();
            Set<PizzaOrder> orderObjs = new HashSet<PizzaOrder>();
            PizzaOrder pizzaOrder1 = new PizzaOrder();
            pizzaOrder1.setOrderDate(new Date());
            pizzaOrder1.setTotalAmount(204.3);
            pizzaOrder1.setSalesBoyId(null);
            orderObjs.add(pizzaOrder1);
            PizzaOrder pizzaOrder2 = new PizzaOrder();
            pizzaOrder2.setOrderDate(new Date());
            pizzaOrder2.setTotalAmount(303.3);
            pizzaOrder2.setSalesBoyId(null);
            orderObjs.add(pizzaOrder2);
            order.createOrder(cust.getCustomerNo(), orderObjs);
            // CreateOrder ends here

            // Create Oder Detail starts here
            order.createOrderDetail(pizzaOrder1.getOrderId(), pizza1.getPizzaId(), 5, 450);
            order.createOrderDetail(pizzaOrder1.getOrderId(), pizza2.getPizzaId(), 3, 300);
            // Create Oder Detail ends here

            // Assign order to salesboy starts here
            SalesBoyDAO salesBoyDAO = new SalesBoyDAO();
            salesBoyDAO.assignOrderToSalesBoy(pizzaOrder1.getOrderId(), 1);
            salesBoyDAO.assignOrderToSalesBoy(pizzaOrder2.getOrderId(), 1);
            // Assign order to salesboy ends here

    /*      PizzaStoreDAO pi = new PizzaStoreDAO();
            pi.findTotalDeliveryMadeByEachSalesBoy();
            pi.findCustomerWhoPlacedLargestNoOfOrders();*/

            // 
        }

    /*  public static void main(String[] args) {
            PizzaStoreDAO pi = new PizzaStoreDAO();
            pi.findTotalDeliveryMadeByEachSalesBoy();
        }*/
    }


    public class CustomerDAO {

        public void storeCustomerDetails(Customer customer, Address address) {
            Session session = null;
            try {
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                customer.setAddress(address);
                session.save(customer);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }

        public void enrollForMemberShipCard(int customerId, MemberShipCard card) {
            Session session = null;
            try {
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                card.setCustomerNo(customerId);
                session.save(card);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }

    }

    public class OrderDAO {

        public void createOrder(int customerId, Set<PizzaOrder> orderObjs) {
            Session session = null;
            try {
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                for (PizzaOrder pizzaOrder : orderObjs) {
                    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                    pizzaOrder.setCustomerNo(customerId);
                    session.save(pizzaOrder);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }

        }

        public void createOrderDetail(int orderId, int pizzaId, int quantity, double price){
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                PizzaOrderDetailId pizzaOrderDetailId = new PizzaOrderDetailId();
                pizzaOrderDetailId.setOrderId(orderId);
                pizzaOrderDetailId.setPizzaId(pizzaId);
                PizzaOrderDetail pizzaOrderDetail = new PizzaOrderDetail();
                pizzaOrderDetail.setPizzaOrderDetailId(pizzaOrderDetailId);
                pizzaOrderDetail.setPrice(price);
                pizzaOrderDetail.setQuantity(quantity);
                session.save(pizzaOrderDetail);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch(HibernateException e){
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally{
                session.close();
            }

        }

    }



    public class PizzaDAO {

    public void createPizzas(Set<Pizza> pizzas){
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            for(Pizza pizza : pizzas){
                if(null != pizza){
                    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                    session.save(pizza);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }   

    }




    public class PizzaStoreDAO {

        public void findTotalDeliveryMadeByEachSalesBoy(){
            Session session = null;
            List<SalesBoy> salesBoys = new ArrayList<SalesBoy>();
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Query query = (Query) session.createQuery("from SalesBoy");
                salesBoys = query.list();
                for(SalesBoy sb : salesBoys){
                    System.out.println("SalesBoy Id :" + sb.getSalesBoyId() + " made -" + sb.getPizzaOrders().size() + " orders");
                }
            } catch(HibernateException e){
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" +e.getMessage());
            } finally{
                session.close();
            }

        }

        public void findCustomerWhoPlacedLargestNoOfOrders(){
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            /*  List list = session.createCriteria(Customer.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("customerNo", customerNo)).list();*/
                Criteria cr1 = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
                Criteria cr2 = cr1.createCriteria("pizzaOrders");
                cr2.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
                List<Customer> list = cr2.list();
                System.out.println("hi");
            } catch (HibernateException e){
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }

        public void getAvailablePizzas(){

        }

    }



    public class SalesBoyDAO {

        public void assignOrderToSalesBoy(int orderId, int salesBoyId){

            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                PizzaOrder pizzaOrder = (PizzaOrder) session.get(PizzaOrder.class, orderId);
                pizzaOrder.setSalesBoyId(salesBoyId);
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.update(pizzaOrder);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e){
                System.out.println("Inside hibernate Exception" + e.getMessage());
            } finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), before asking a question.

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here. Also, what does "isn't working properly" mean? We have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Please read [ask].